# Finding the length of the kernel of a map in Macaulay2

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomial-rings, monomial-ideals, macaulay2

Given an equigenerated monomial ideal $I$ over a polynomial ring, I am trying to check if a sequence $L={l_1,\ldots,l_t}$ is almost $I$-regular, i.e. for each $i$, the kernel of the multiplication map $.l_i: \frac{I}{(l_1,\ldots,l_{i-1})I}\to \frac{I}{(l_1,\ldots,l_{i-1})I}$ is of finite length. How is it possible to check this using Macaulay2? Actually, I am not able to define the map using the code "map()" for modules. Next the code "length" only computes the length of a list. Does the code "degree" measure the length of a module? 
Since the kernel of the above map is $$\{f\in I:\ fl_i\in (l_1,\ldots,l_{i-1})I\},$$, one way is to check the length of this ideal. How can one define thisideal in Macaulay2?

I am also wondering if there is a way to check if the list L is a regular sequence of I. The code "isRegularSequence" only works for the ring.

Comment: What is your level of experience with M2?

Comment: @Youngsu  Not a high level. I am in learning level.

Comment: Your last question is not hard as there is a characterization of depth in terms of Ext modules which M2 can compute. For instance, $Ext^2(R^1/J,R)$ can be computed in M2, where $R$ is the ambient ring and $J$ is an ideal. As you know, the depth is the first non-vanishing Ext, so by varying the exponent, you can check the depth.

Comment: For the first question, you may want to express the kernel as an ideal of your ring. If the height of the ideal is equal to the dimension of the ring, then it is of finite length (assuming minor conditions). For instance, the kernel of $\cdot f \colon I/J \to I/J$ corresponds to the ideal $J :_I f = (J:f) \cap I$.